# error UnsuportedClassVersionError

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

I compiled with 1.7 jdk a webApp it works fine at local server but when I upload to my VPS I got an error "UnsuportedClassVersionError Unsuported major.minor version 51.0" my server has jdk 1.7 too so I don't know whaty's wrong.

local:
Java -version
java version 1.7.0_21

VPS
java -version
java version 1.7.0_03

Comment: 1) Pleased **edit** your question rather than delete earlier versions! 2) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Comment: What web application server are you using? It's possible that the app server is pointing to a different JVM than the one on your path.

Comment: I did a servlet and I create de .war and I upload to tomcat 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a matter of the difference of the latest 2 numbers, but I compilde again with 1.6 and the web apps works fine.